# Splitting a line with regular expression library re

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and I am trying to split a line using re library but the list contains the "spaces".

```
import re
BoW = {}
f = open('TestPython.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    for word in re.split(" |,|, |\n|\.",line.rstrip()):
        if word in BoW.keys():
            BoW[word]+=1    
        else:
            BoW[word]=1 
print(BoW)
key = max(BoW, key=lambda k: BoW[k])
print({key})
```

This is the result I get with space having a frequency of 2.

```
{'This': 1, 'is': 1, 'a': 1, 'test': 1, 'document': 1, 
 '': 2, 'To': 1, 'read': 1, 'the': 2, 'file;': 1, 'line': 2, 
 'by': 1, 'Thanks': 1, 'and': 1, 'Regards': 1}
{''}
```

Is there anything wrong with my regular expression?
Any suggestion would help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you separately denote your sample string and the **exact** output you want to end up with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those empty strings (not "spaces") come from either two consecutive matches of your given pattern, or the match being at either ends of the string, so for example splitting a string of two commas `,,` with your regex would result in 3 empty strings--one before the commas, one between the commas and one after the comma.

For your purpose you should use `re.findall` instead to avoid getting the empty strings:

```
for word in re.findall(r'[^ .,\n]+', line):
```